# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field for time

Tags: java, android, time, static

Hello I am trying to code the time for Android development

```
import android.text.format.Time;
```

This is my code in the `MainActivity` class within the protected void `onCreate`.

```
TextView abc;
abc= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockTextView);
abc.setText("Time is " + Time.hour + ":" + Time.minute);
```

Why do I keep getting the error `Cannnot make a static reference to the non-static field Time.hour` and how would I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: create an object and then use it.. go through core java tutorials before starting with android

Comment: @Pragnani - That's incorrect. `Time.hour` and `Time.minute` are _instance_ fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hour` and `minute` fields of `android.text.format.Time` are instance fields. You need to create an instance of `Time` to access them:

```
TextView abc;
Time time = new Time(); // initialized to January 1, 1970 in default time zone
time.setToNow();
abc= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockTextView);
abc.setText("Time is " + time.hour + ":" + time.minute);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Cannnot make a static reference to the non-static field Time.hour

This is because you are trying to access non-static fields in a static way. 
`Time.hour` is an instance field **(not static)**, so calling it as `Time.hour` makes no sense, as you dont have `Time` instance.

You need to create a `Time` object and then you can use `myTime.hour`.

Comment: Time.hour and Time.minute are not static field!

Comment: This is backwards, isn't it? `Time.hour` and `Time.minute` are _not_ static fields. It doesn't matter if they are being accessed from a static method or not; they cannot be accessed without an instance of a `Time` object. The error message even makes the point: "the **non-static** field Time.hour"

Comment: Maybe you mix hour and HOUR

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Almost all of it! Time.hour is **instance** field, and to access a static fields in non static method you **dont need** to create a class object.

Comment: @baraky I got you I got confuse just reading this `Cannnot make a static reference to the non-static` in whether those were static or instance fiels. Now I was commenting on other answer. Sorry So I could not edit that time..Thanks...